# Merge 'issue-tracker' and 'support-tracker'?

Tags: discussion, tag-merge

I've just stumbled upon two tags which seem to address the very same purpose:

- [issue-tracker](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracker) × 23
- [support-tracker](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support-tracker) × 13

Before merging the two, I'd like to ask for consent. My proposal would be making `issue-tracker` the target, and `support-tracker` a synonym to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think these tags should definitely be merged. [issue-tracker](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracker) and [support-tracker](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support-tracker) to me seem to mean the same thing. If one of the tags were, say, [bug-tracker](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug-tracker) then I could see how it would relate to code; however, just the word, "issue" really doesn't apply only to code but could mean any issue. [Referencing Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_tracking_system),

> An issue tracking system (also ITS, trouble ticket system, support ticket, request management or incident ticket system) is a computer software package that manages and maintains lists of issues, as needed by an organization.

It seems that support ticket and issue tracker are the same, and I'm sure you could link `support-tracker` with `support ticket` as well.

I also agree with making [issue-tracker](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracker) the target as it has more questions associated with it and, from what I understand, it is more well known than [support-tracker](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support-tracker).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this. [issue-tracker](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracker) sounds to me like (and seems to be used for) questions about... 'issue trackers': things to track bugs in, e.g., code.

[support-tracker](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support-tracker) feels like something the manage incoming emails, phone calls, etc. from customers, and to track tickets created due to those 'support' incidents.

Comment: OK, but then we might need to at least retag some questions from support to issue (or remove the support tag), e.g. [GitHub, but without an account for issue submission (Or a similarly simple bug tracker)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18288/185), [How to check my mobile network open ports?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14217/185). And apart from what you use it for, the same software can do both (as you can use any bottle for milk or beer – the former for the infant, the latter for its dad ;) Are they really that much different?

Comment: @Izzy I'd say they're different enough that we should keep both. Some pruning is needed; but the underlying tags should be able to stay IMO.

Comment: OK, definitely agreed on the pruning (done that ;). Leaving the rest alone until a counter-answer comes up and exceeds yours in votes :)